# JavaScript, regex: How to fetch mail address in mailto: links

Tags: javascript, regex, mailto

Is there a jquery plugin or may be a regex which can be used to all the fields in query string of a mailto: link. It should support the [mailto syntax](http://zoomquiet.org/res/scrapbook/ZqSKM/data/20100419224556/).

Say if I have a link like ...

```
<a href="mailto:astark1@unl.edu,id@internet.node">Some msg</a>
```

The regex should give me the mail addresses in mailto: link - `astark1@unl.edu`, `id@internet.node`. It should also support links like

```
<a href="mailto:astark1@unl.edu?subject=Comments from MailTo Syntax Page">
<a href="mailto:astark1@unl.edu?body=I am having trouble finding information on">
<a href="mailto:astark1@unl.edu?subject=MailTo Comments&cc=ASTARK1@UNL.EDU&bcc=id@internet.node">
```

For a link like

```
<a href="mailto:value">tell a friend</a>
```

I would pass `value` and the function and get an associative array of email addresses and other fields passed in query string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parsing URLs, and especially their query strings, is not a job for regexes. You could use [a proper URL-parsing library](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/url.js) or perhaps just a [query string parsing one](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/querystring.js).

Comment: Really? hundreds of lines of code to pull out an email address?

Comment: Yes. Anyone who says otherwise doesn't understand the full complexity of URLs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how accurate this is, but it might be improved if you feel a necessity to use regex.

```
function getEmails(str) {
// returns a list of email addresses in 'str'
    var tags = str.match(/<a href=('|")mailto:(.*?)\1(.*?)>/gi);
    var res = [];
    if (!tags.length) return res;
    for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        tags[i] = tags[i].replace(/^<a href=('|")mailto:(.+?)(\?[^\1]*)?\1>$/,'$2');
        var arr = tags[i].replace(/\s/g,'').split(',');
        for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) res.push(arr[j]);
    }
    return res;
}
```

I'm not sure what you mean in the last part by the way so I tried to answer the first part.

Comment: I don't know if this satisfies the OP's needs, but this does exactly what I was after. Thanks! (Also thanks for not posting a "don't do this" answer :)

Answer (score 0):

**If you know what you are doing :**

```
var href = 'mailto:hello@world.com?subject=My+Subject&body=My+Body';

function getMailto(s) {
    var r = {};
    var email = s.match(/mailto:([^\?]*)/);
            email = email[1] ? email[1] : false;
  var subject = s.match(/subject=([^&]+)/);
            subject = subject ? subject[1].replace(/\+/g,' ') : false;
    var body = s.match(/body=([^&]+)/);
            body = body ? body[1].replace(/\+/g,' ') : false;

  if(email) {r['email'] = email;}
  if(subject) {r['subject'] = subject;}
  if(body) {r['body'] = body;}

  return r;
}

console.log(getMailto(href));
```

**Demo :** https://jsfiddle.net/l2aelba/qov9wpk5/

Comment: +1 for adding a solution rather than saying you shouldn't do it! , although the method name in the console.log in inconsistent, and needs to be stringified.

Comment: -1 This parsing is completely insufficient for [URL decoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) in general. For example, if the subject contains an exclamation mark, it will have been encoded as `%21`, which your code would leave as-is.

Comment: @Anko This is just "use on your own risk!"

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```js
function parseMailTo(mailto) {
  var url = new URL(mailto)
  var query = parseQuery(url.search)
  return {
    to: {url.pathname}
    subject: {query.subject}
  }
}

function parseQuery(queryString) {
  var query = {};
  var pairs = (queryString[0] === '?' ? queryString.substr(1) : queryString).split('&');
  for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
      var pair = pairs[i].split('=');
      query[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1] || '');
  }
  return query;
}
```